# Select record based on date/time range based on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, date

I have following table structure

```
id          date             time            discount
------------------------------------------------------
1         2015-08-10       09:30:00           50%
2         2016-04-15       14:00:00           30%
3         2018-01-25       18:15:00           75%
4         2018-11-19       11:45:00           45%
```

I want to query this table to find the discount amount on specific date;

expected result;

if I query for a date between `2015-08-10 09:30:00` - `2016-04-15 13:59:59` it should result `50%`

for a date between `2016-04-15 14:00:00` - `2018-01-25 18:14:59`, should result `30%`

example:

> Query to this table for date `2016-01-10 08:00:00` should
>   result `50%`

I have searched through SO & Google but couldn't find a solution for my case;

Tried a query for my example like

```
SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE date<='2016-01-10' AND time<='08:00:00'
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

but no luck!

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this for your table structure -

SELECT discount FROM discounts WHERE CAST(CONCAT(date, “ “, time) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN “2015-08-10 09:30:00” AND “2016-04-15 13:59:59”

You might be able to get away without casting the values but this will ensure your date and time values are correctly formatted.

However I would suggest storing the date and time values as a single standard datetime value. Is there a reason why you have it as two separate columns?

Comment: Thanks for input, however we don't want to pass two dates  to check the in between, my original question is to get the discount on the base of given single date/time input.